# How do I get an array of file names from the iOS File Manager

Tags: arrays, swift, nsfilemanager

I'm creating an Audio Recording app and have declared an empty array to store all the names of the files.

```
var recordingTitles: [String] = []
```

When I launch the app, I have a function that checks what files are already stored in the File Manager and returns the number of files in order to display the correct number of cells in the collectionView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getNumberOfRecordings()

}

// Get number of actual recording files stored in the File Manager Directory
func getNumberOfRecordings() {
    let directoryUrl = getDirectory()

    do {
        contentsOfFileManager = try myFileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: directoryUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: [URLResourceKey(rawValue: recordingsKey)], options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    numberOfRecordings = contentsOfFileManager.count
}
```

I would like to obtain the names of the files and assign them to the "recordingTitles" array in order to display the correct title for each cell. I've tried reading over the Apple docs for [File Manager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) but haven't found a solution yet. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What output do you get right now? An empty list? An error?

Comment: Thank you for your help @skylerl. The `recordingTitles` array starts out empty, and so when the app tries to load the titles based on the number of files currently in the File Manager Directory I get an "Index out of range".
My `getNumberOfRecordings()` function goes through the process of getting an array of URLs from the File Manager, but I'm not sure how to obtain just the file names and convert them to an array of Strings to assign to the `recordingTitles`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `contentsOfFileManager` is going to consist of [`NSURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl) objects. These objects have different fields you can pluck out and use. It looks like you're interested in just the filename so I'd like to draw your attention to the [`lastPathComponent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417444-lastpathcomponent) field of NSURL. From the docs:

> This property contains the last path component, unescaped using the replacingPercentEscapes(using:) method. For example, in the URL file:///path/to/file, the last path component is file.

In other words, calling `myNsurl.lastPathComponent` should yield you the filename. So you can loop through the array that's returned by `myFileManager.contentsOfDirectory` and get the `lastPathComponent` of each one and add them to another array which will contain just the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `map` function. You probably want something like this:

```
recordingTitles = try myFileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at:directoryURL, 
    includingPropertiesForKeys: nil).map {$0.lastPathComponent}
```